# Spark-R: How to transform Cassandra map and array columns into new DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, sparkr, spark-cassandra-connector

Using SparkR (spark-2.1.0) using the DataStax cassandra connector.

I have a dataframe which connects to a table in Cassandra. Some of the columns in the cassandra table are of type map and set. I need to perform various filtering/aggregation operations on these "collection" columns.

```
my_data_frame <-read.df(
    source = "org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra",
    keyspace = "my_keyspace", table = "some_table")

my_data_frame
SparkDataFrame[id:string,  col2:map<string,int>, col3:array<string>]

schema(my_data_frame)
StructType
|-name = "id", type = "StringType", nullable = TRUE
|-name = "col2", type = "MapType(StringType,IntegerType,true)", nullable = TRUE
|-name = "col3", type = "ArrayType(StringType,true)", nullable = TRUE
```

I would like to obtain:

1. A new dataframe containing the unique string KEYS in the col2 map over all rows in my_data_frame.
2. The sum() of VALUES in the col2 map for each row placed into a new column in my_data_frame.
3. The set of unique values in the col3 array over all rows in my_data_frame into a new dataframe

The map data in cassandra for col2 looks like:
    VALUES ({'key1':100, 'key2':20, 'key3':50, ... })

If the original cassandra table looks like:

```
id   col2
1    {'key1':100, 'key2':20}
2    {'key3':40,  'key4':10}
3    {'key1':10,  'key3':30}
```

I would like to obtain a dataframe containing the unique keys:

```
col2_keys
key1
key2
key3
key4
```

The sum of values for each id:

```
id  col2_sum
1   120
2   60
3   40
```

The max of values for each id:

```
id  col2_max
1   100
2   40
3   30
```

Additional info:

```
col2_df <- select(my_data_frame, my_data_frame$col2)
```

head(col2_df)

```
                           col2
1 <environment: 0x7facfb4fc4e8>
2 <environment: 0x7facfb4f3980>
3 <environment: 0x7facfb4eb980>
4 <environment: 0x7facfb4e0068>

row1 <- first(my_data_frame)
row1
                           col2
1 <environment: 0x7fad00023ca0>
```

I am new to Spark and R and have probably missed something obvious, but I don't 
see any obvious functions for transforming maps and arrays in this manner.

I did see some references to using "environment" as a map in R but am not sure how that would work for my requirements.

```
spark-2.1.0
Cassandra 3.10
spark-cassandra-connector:2.0.0-s_2.11
JDK 1.8.0_101-b13
```

Thanks so much in advance for any help.

Comment: please share example data and expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your response. An example would definitely help.  I've updated the question.

Comment: Did you figure out how to solve this? I am trying to find answers for a similar situation.